# How to specify ACL for an object in an S3 using the java API?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to grant full control and am using this:

```
 PutObjectAclRequest newAcl = PutObjectAclRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucket)
                    .key(objectKey)
                    .grantFullControl(id)
                    .build();
```

This gives an error: "Argument format not recognized". What is the correct format for granting full control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out. An interesting format: "id=abc".

Full code:

```
S3AsyncClient client = S3AsyncClient.builder()
                        .credentialsProvider(credentials)
                        .build()
PutObjectAclRequest newAcl = PutObjectAclRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucket)
                    .key(objectKey)
                    .grantFullControl("id=" + id)
                    .build();
            client.putObjectAcl(newAcl)
                    .get();
```